# Difference of "and" and "&"

Tags: translation

I want to translate the name of my college from Chinese into English.

The translation is like that **"Guangxi Vocational and Technical College of Communications"**, but if I wish to make this name shorter, I think "&" is interchangeable with "and", but I am told that it is informal if you use a symbol rather than a word.

So what is the difference?

Comment: Do you know, the well-known university, Texas A&M? So, I think it's not very informal to do so; but I am a learner and that's just an educated guess.

Comment: [Related on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/when-to-use-instead-of-and)

Comment: I am Czech but I think you can usually see & when there's a pair of something.

Answer (score 2):

The ampersand (**&**) is considered to be used mostly in informal writing. Different style guides give different recommendations.

> Some style guides allow ampersands as part of a formal company name (Smith & Wesson, Tiffany & Co.). Other style guides recommend spelling out the **and** in such cases. Most style guides recommend using the ampersand when the rest of the name is also an abbreviation (AT&T) and in common expressions (R&D). As you see here, there are no spaces on either side of the ampersand when it is used that way.

I like the answers of Robert Charles and Alankar Paul on [**Quora**](https://www.quora.com/When-do-you-use-instead-of-and):

> There's a tradition in editorial work of using the ampersand (&) for internal documents and pre-publication copy. The ampersand therefore becomes a sort of automatic cue for editors to see that the copy is either unedited or unready for release. It's also a kind of safeguard against accidental release or use of copy, since typesetters generally will do an "&" search during or before final page makeup. Sometimes, by dint of habit, these people would carry over in using & in other activities, e.g. on the Internet. Generally, & shouldn't be used in regular correspondence except in some company or organisation names.

---

> It is considered more suitable to use 'and' in formal writing, especially when mentioning names of people, companies, government agencies. (like Road and Transportation Department instead of Road & Transportation Department).
>
> Where may the ampersand be used:
>
> - It is often used in Business names and should always be mentioned that way. e.g: Reid & Taylor, AT&T
> - When mentioning a family/couple or an address. e.g: Mrs & Mr Smith, Mr John & Family
> - When citing sources, if there are multiple authors in a source. (with exceptions) e.g: Nevid, Rathus, & Greene, 2008.

**Do not use an ampersand in general writing simply to abbreviate the word and. For example:**

- We need to reorder toner cartridges and paper. (**Good**)
- We need to reorder toner cartridges & paper. (**Bad**)

Comment: @NanningYouth You're welcome, my friend!